# How to get json data in react render?

Tags: json, reactjs

What I am trying to do grab json data to render it as an element. Here is what I have, but `this.images` continues to come up empty(and undefined/null if I don't set it at the top.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.images = [];
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('grid-config.json')
    .then((res) => {
      this.setImageArray(res.data);
    });
  }

  setImageArray(imageArray) {
    let newArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
      newArray.push(imageArray[i]);
    }
    this.images = newArray;
   }


  render() {
    const postData = this.props.images;
    console.log(this.images);
    return (
      <div>
       hello
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please check the browser console and see if there's any error there?

Comment: There is not, I checked. The only thing in the console is [] --> which is for console.log(this.images)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the component's *state* to hold the image data; when this is updated it will cause the component to render (React will call its *render* function.)

So, for example, set the component's state something like this:

```
    setImageArray(imageArray) {
    let newArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
      newArray.push(imageArray[i]);
    }
    this.setState({images: newArray });
   }
```

and also initialise this, for example, in the component's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { images: [] };
  }
```

You access the data in the *render* function as *this.state.images*.

{*See the section entitled* A Stateful Component *at* https://facebook.github.io/react/ }

Comment: Small typo in your code, `this.setState({ images: newArray })`.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you must only manipulate with your state instead of class property. Use `setState` method to update your component state. And render images from your updated state.

```
export default class Grid extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { images: [] };
  }

 componentWillMount() {
  axios.get('grid-config.json')
   .then((res) => {
    this.setImageArray(res.data);
  });
 }

 setImageArray(imageArray) {
  let newArray = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(imageArray[i]);
  }
  this.setState({ images: newArray });
 }


 render() {
  const postData = this.state.images;
  console.log(postData);
  return (
   <div>
    hello
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Try this code to render images;

Answer (score 0):

1. React components will call render only if the state is changed
   (except in special cases like initial render or when forceUpdate is
   called).
2. Your axios call is async and component is already rendered by the
   time it executes.
3. Thus, the render function is called when images is `[]`, and never called again.
4. To force a re-render, you have to store the response in state, as
   pointed in multiple answers or use forceUpdate (not recommended).

**EDIT**

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myName = "Sachin"
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myName = 'Jamie';

      // If this is commented out, new value will not reflect in UI.
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, {this.myName}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See this code pen link : https://codepen.io/sach11/pen/ayJaXb

Its very similar to your code, just replaced axios call with a setTimeout.

On line 16, I have a forceUpdate(), which forces a re-render and reflects the new value of this.myName. Otherwise although value is updated, it does not reflect as render is not called again.

Comment: When I console.log(this) in the render function though it prints with the image object in it. Why is that?

Comment: @Jamie as I already pointed out, 'images' is added to the class instance as soon as you define it in constructor. But its values get populated only after axios call is completed. Thus, 'this' has a property called 'image', but in first render its value will be '[]'.  If you can trigger render function again, you will see the actual values inside it.

Comment: @Jamie I've updated my answer with a codepen link, check that out.